# My duplicates aren't using my pitcher pump

Tags: oxygen-not-included

I have a pitcher pump right above oil, but the duplicates won't use the pump to carry the oil over to a bottler with oil selected. I've checked priorities; however, nothing is working.

Comment: Is auto-bottling enabled on your bottler?

Comment: Is it too hot? Pitcher pumps can overheat.